# UPDATE múltiple y simultaneo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy trantando de hacer un `UPDATE` multiple, pero no logro hacer que funcione. He intentado de diferentes maneras y ninguna me funciona. Cabe señalar que el máximo de filas son 36, por lo cual, se debe de poder actualizar de 1 a 36 datos.

Ejemplo de la consulta que ocupo en MySQL:

**UPDATE tbl_material_in_out SET location="EMBARQUES" WHERE skmx_pn="3201196" AND lote="02091901A02" AND quantity="3000"**

Este código pertenece a mi formulario:

```
<form method="post" name="crear-out" id="crear_out" action="modelo-out.php" onsubmit="return validar();">
    <!-- Los datos se pueden desplegar hasta 36 veces -->
    <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) { ?>
            <tr class="fila-fija">
                <input type="hidden" style="width : 140px;" id="customer<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer[]" placeholder="customer" />
                <input type="hidden" id="folio<?php echo ($i); ?>" name="folio[]" value="<?php echo $f; ?>">
                <td><input onchange="consult(), validarskmx(this);" type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="skmx_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="skmx_pn[]" placeholder="SKMX PN" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width : 180px;" id="description<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="description[]" placeholder="Description" readonly /></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="customer_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer_pn[]" placeholder="Customer PN" readonly /></td>
                <td><input onchange='return validarSO(this)' type="text" style="width : 120px;" id="shop_order<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="shop_order[]" placeholder="# Shop Order" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width : 70px;" id="po<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="po[]" placeholder="# P.O." readonly></td>
                <td><input onchange='return validarLOTE(this)' type="text" style="width : 100px;" id="lote<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="lote[]" placeholder="Lote" /></td>
                <td><input onchange='return validarQT(this)' class="quantity" type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="quantity<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="location<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="location[]" placeholder="Location" value="EMBARQUES" readonly /></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="incoming<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="incoming[]" placeholder="" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- </table> -->
    <div class="box-footer"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="actualizar">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-in-out" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Crear</button>
        <a href="in-out.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Aquí mi código PHP. Aquí necesito que se cumplan 3 condiciones para que se pueda actualizar los valores.

```
 try {
    foreach (array_keys($_POST['skmx_pn']) as $key) {
        $location = $_POST['location'][$key];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
        $skmx_pn = $_POST['skmx_pn'][$key];
        $lote = $_POST['lote'][$key];
        $name_loc = $_SESSION['nombre'];

        $update = 'UPDATE tbl_material_in_out SET location = "' . $location . '", name_loc = "' . $name_loc . '"
                    WHERE skmx_pn ="' . $skmx_pn . '" & lote ="' . $lote . '" & quantity ="' . $quantity . '"';
        echo mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    }

    if ($conn->affected_rows) {
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'exito'
        );
    } else {
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'error'
        );
    }
    $conn->close();
    // die(json_encode($respuesta));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
}
```

No me tira ningun error la sentencia, solo no funciona.
Como les digo, he estado investigando formas diferentes de hacerlo pero ninguna me ha funcionado.

Lo siguiente es lo que me arroja el `var_dump();`. Los datos que ocupo para el **UPDATE** son: **lote, location, skmx_pn y quantity**. Los otros datos los ocupare en otra consulta aparte dentro del mismo documento.

```
array(12) {
  ["registro"]=&gt;
  string(10) "actualizar"
  ["customer"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(22) "STANLEY BLACK &amp; DECKER"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(22) "STANLEY BLACK &amp; DECKER"
  }
  ["folio"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(12) "120421082348"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(12) "120421082348"
  }
  ["skmx_pn"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(7) "3201224"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(7) "3201196"
  }
  ["description"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(10) "CLAMP CORD"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(17) "SA SPINDLE BUTTON"
  }
  ["customer_pn"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(9) "655058-00"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(9) "395414-00"
  }
  ["shop_order"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(9) "WK19-0041"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(9) "WK17-0034"
  }
  ["po"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    [1]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["lote"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(11) "13051902A02"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(11) "02091901A02"
  }
  ["quantity"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(4) "3000"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(4) "3000"
  }
  ["location"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(9) "EMBARQUES"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(9) "EMBARQUES"
  }
  ["incoming"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(8) "Incoming"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
  }
}
11{"respuesta":"error"}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta parte de la salida de `var_dump($_POST);` para poder sugerirte alguna respuesta óptima? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar esa salida en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, ya la actualize

Comment: Ok, en la salida yo veo un array anidado, pero analizando tu código no logro entender lo que quieres sacar del $_POST  ni cómo lo quieres (con qué estructura). Viendo la salida del `var_dump`, ¿podrías verbalizar tu problema, es decir, explicar con palabras por qué estás organizando así los datos y qué quieres obtener de ellos? Ayudaría mucho que pongas un ejemplo de como debería quedar al menos una consulta  UPDATE de las que intentas construir.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Ya lo actualice, espero haber podido aclarar los puntos que señalas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en cada uno de los sub-arrays hay la misma cantidad de elementos (es lo que intuyo por tu intento con `array_keys`), puedes resolverlo contando la cantidad de elementos que hay `$_POST['skmx_pn']` (o en cualquiera de los otros elementos anidados) y usar ese índice para leer cada elemento de $_POST` que te interese.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```
$r=array();
for($key = 0, $size = count($_POST['skmx_pn']); $key < $size; ++$key) { 
        $location = $_POST['location'][$key];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
        $skmx_pn = $_POST['skmx_pn'][$key];
        $lote = $_POST['lote'][$key];
        $name_loc = $_SESSION['nombre'];

        $update = "UPDATE tbl_material_in_out SET location = '$location', name_loc ='$name_loc'
                    WHERE skmx_pn ='$skmx_pn' AND lote ='$lote' AND quantity ='$quantity'";
        $aRows=$conn->affected_rows;
        if ( $conn->query($update) && $aRows>0 ) {
            $r[]="Índice $key filas insertadas: $aRows";
        } else {
            $r[]="Error en el UPDATE de índice $key";
        }
} 

# Retornar o hacer lo que sea con $r
```

### Algunas recomendaciones y notas

- He simplificado tu consulta UPDATE. No hacen falta tantas concatenaciones si usas comillas dobles para toda la cadena. De todos modos deberías usar una consulta preparada en este caso.
- He controlado cada UPDATE dentro del bucle, no fuera, cada UPDATE es individual, uno puede fallar y otro no, no tiene sentido controlar las filas afectadas sólo una vez fuera del bucle. De todos modos este tipo de operaciones masivas suelen hacerse con transacciones (si la tabla es InnoDB).
- No entiendo por qué usas `try ... catch` cuando este código no levantaría Excepciones, a no ser que hayas escrito tu propio manejador de excepciones ¿? No me meto en esa parte, he puesto un comentario al final del bucle, para que retornes a `$r` desde donde sea.
- Evita mezclar estilos. Estabas usando estilo procedural y orientado a objetos mezclados. Aunque no es motivo de error, sí es una mala práctica que conviene evitar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y comentarios, los tomare en cuenta ya que soy nuevo en esto. El código funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JoseFernando me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto, un saludo.